# How to display only the necessary component

Tags: reactjs, popup, fullcalendar, crud

I am trying to create a custom calendar using the react `FullCalendar` component. The calendar can do `CRUD` operations, my problem is in displaying `popup` windows that send `requests` to the `server`. At one time the event edit window and event delete window are displayed, even if I set in `onClick` event to show only DeleteEvent component `setIsDeleteModalOpen(true);` and EditEvent to hide `setIsEditModalOpen(false);` both components are displayed at the same time.

Which I think is due to the fact that in this method, which displays the edit window if the user clicks on the event

```
const handleEventClick = (arg) => {
        setSelectedEvent(arg.event);
        setIsEditModalOpen(true);
    };
```

So how can I solve this?

EditEvent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const EditEvent = ({ initialValues, handleUpdate, onClose, isOpen, onReload }) => {
    const [id, setId] = useState(initialValues?.id || null);
    const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialValues?.description || "");
    const [date, setDate] = useState(initialValues?.date || "");
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

    const handleDescriptionChange = (event) => {
        setDescription(event.target.value);
    };

    const handleDateChange = (event) => {
        setDate(event.target.value);
    };
  

   
    const onUpdate = (updatedEvent) => {
        axios
            .put(`/api/calendar/event/put/${updatedEvent.id}`, updatedEvent)
            .then((response) => {
                // handle successful response
                console.log(response.data);
                handleUpdate(response.data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                // handle error response
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
    
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!description) {
            setErrorMessage("Please provide a description");
            return;
        }
        const updatedEvent = {
            id: initialValues ? initialValues.id : null,
            description,
            date,
        };
        console.log(id);
        onUpdate(updatedEvent);
        onClose();
        onReload();
    };

    return (
        <>
            {isOpen && (
                <div className="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
                    <div className="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">
                        <div className="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
                        </div>

                        <span className="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>

                        <div className="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pt-5 pb-4 text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full sm:p-6">
                            <div>
                                <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                                    <h3 className="text-lg leading-6 font-medium text-gray-900">Edit Event</h3>
                                    <div className="mt-2">
                                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                            <div className="mb-4">
                                                <label htmlFor="description" className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">
                                                    Description
                                                </label>
                                                <input
                                                    type="text"
                                                    id="description"
                                                    name="description"
                                                    className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                    value={description}
                                                    onChange={handleDescriptionChange}
                                                    maxLength={255}
                                                />
                                                {errorMessage && (
                                                    <p className="text-red-500 text-xs italic mt-2">{errorMessage}</p>
                                                )}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="mb-4">
                                                <label htmlFor="date" className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2">
                                                    Date
                                                </label>
                                                <input
                                                    type="date"
                                                    id="date"
                                                    name="date"
                                                    className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                                    value={date}
                                                    onChange={handleDateChange}
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="flex justify-end">
                                                <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                                                    onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, id)}
                                                >
                                                    Update
                                                </button>
                                                <button
                                                    type="button"
                                                    className="ml-2 inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-gray-700 bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500"
                                                    onClick={onClose}
                                                >
                                                    Cancel
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );

};

export default EditEvent;
```

DeleteEvent component

```
import React from "react";

const DeleteEvent = ({ event, onDelete, isOpen }) => {
    const handleDelete = () => {
        alert("Deleted");
    };

    return (
        <>
            {isOpen && (
                <div>
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete this event?</p>
                    <p>{event.description}</p>
                    <p>{event.date}</p>
                    <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default DeleteEvent;
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import CreateEvent from './CreateEvent';
import EditEvent from './EditEvent';
import DeleteEvent from './DeleteEvent';
import axios from 'axios';


function FullComponent() {
    const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
    const [isCreateModalOpen, setIsCreateModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isEditModalOpen, setIsEditModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isDeleteModalOpen, setIsDeleteModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
    const [selectedEvent, setSelectedEvent] = useState(null);

    const updateEvents = (updatedEvent) => {
        setEvents((prevEvents) =>
            prevEvents.map((event) => (event.id === updatedEvent.id ? updatedEvent : event))
        );
    };
    
    const handleDateClick = (arg) => {
        setSelectedDate(arg.date);
        setIsCreateModalOpen(true);
    };

    const handleEventClick = (arg) => {
        setSelectedEvent(arg.event);
        setIsEditModalOpen(true);
    };

    const handleEventAdded = (event) => {
        setEvents([...events, event]);
        setIsCreateModalOpen(false);
    };

    const handleEventEdited = (event) => {
        const newEvents = events.map((e) => {
            if (e.id === event.id) {
                return { ...e, ...event };
            }
            return e;
        });
        setEvents(newEvents);
        setIsEditModalOpen(false);
    };

    const handleEventDeleted = (event) => {
        const newEvents = events.filter((e) => e.id !== event.id);
        setEvents(newEvents);
        setIsDeleteModalOpen(false);
    };



    const handleReload = () => {
        axios.get('/api/calendar/events').then((response) => {
            const mappedEvents = response.data.map((event) => ({
                id: event.id,
                title: event.description, // Use description as the event title
                start: new Date(event.date),
                allDay: true
            }));
            setEvents(mappedEvents);
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch events from API endpoint and map them to FullCalendar event objects
        axios.get('/api/calendar/events').then((response) => {
            const mappedEvents = response.data.map((event) => ({
                id: event.id,
                title: event.description, // Use description as the event title
                start: new Date(event.date),
                allDay: true 
            }));
            setEvents(mappedEvents);
        });
    }, []);

    const renderEventContent = (eventInfo) => {
        // Render the event title and description
        return (
            <>
                <b>{eventInfo.timeText}</b>
                <p>{eventInfo.event.title}</p>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    setSelectedEvent(eventInfo.event);
                    setIsDeleteModalOpen(true);
                    setIsEditModalOpen(false);
                }}>X</button>
            </>
        );
    };

    return (
        <>
            <FullCalendar
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                dateClick={handleDateClick}
                eventClick={handleEventClick}
                events={events}
                eventContent={renderEventContent} // Use custom event renderer

            />
            {isCreateModalOpen && (
                <CreateEvent
                    isOpen={isCreateModalOpen}
                    onClose={() => setIsCreateModalOpen(false)}
                    date={selectedDate}
                    onEventAdded={handleEventAdded}

                />
            )}
            {isEditModalOpen && selectedEvent &&(
                <EditEvent
                    isOpen={isEditModalOpen}
                    onClose={() => setIsEditModalOpen(false)}
                    initialValues={selectedEvent}
                    onEventEdited={handleEventEdited}
                    handleUpdate={updateEvents}
                    onReload={handleReload}
                />
            )}

            {isDeleteModalOpen && (
                <DeleteEvent
                    isOpen={isDeleteModalOpen}
                    onClose={() => setIsDeleteModalOpen(false)}
                    event={selectedEvent}
                    onEventDeleted={handleEventDeleted}
                />
            )}
        </>
    );
}

export default FullComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add popup components into array and by clicking event change index of this array.

```
const arr = [<firstwindow />, <secondwindow />]
const [i,setI] = useState[-1]

....

return (<>
  ...
  {i!==-1 &&<>{arr[i]}</>
</>)
```

By manipulating i you can show different components in array, and if you set i to -1 no popups will be shown

Comment: it looks promising, I assume that this should I implement tu FullComponent?